# File Routing with MAMP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been teaching myself php from a book called "PHP and MySQL - Web Development," and was going through the example provided in it to practice. It asks you to make a simple order form using html and create a php file called "processorder.php" which should appear upon submitting the order form. Below is the code for the form page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bob's Auto Parts - Place an Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/processorder.php" 
method="post"> 
        <table style = "border: opx;">
        <tr style = "background: #cccccc;">
            <td style = "width: 150px; text-align: center;">Item</td>
            <td style = "width: 15px; text-align: 
center;">Quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tires</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "tireqty" size = "3" 
maxlength = "3" /></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>Oil</td>
            <td><input type = "text" name = "oilqty" size = "3" maxlength = "3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spark Plugs</td>
        <td><input type = "text" name = "sparkqty" size = "3" 
maxlength = "3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan = "2" style = "text-align: center;"><input 
type = "submit" value = "Submit Order" /></td>
        </tr>   
        </table>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bob's Auto Parts - Order Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bob's Auto Parts</h1>
    <h2>Order Results</h2>
        <?php
            echo '<p>Order processed.</p>';
        ?>      
</body>
</html>
```

I've made sure to put the php file in the right directory, but when I run all this using MAMP, I get an error saying "The requested URL /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/processorder.php was not found on this server." Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to php, and any advice would be welcomed.

Comment: try just `<form action = "/processorder.php" 
method="post"> `

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will automatically pull files based on its web root. In your case apache is pointed to `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs`. So all file paths you give should be relative to that directory allow you to use just `/processorder.php`.

It worth noting that if you have a leading slash `/` it will be relative to webroot while if you do not it will be relative to the current directory. e.g if you are at `/hello/world.php` and put the action as `processorder.php` it will submit to `/hello/processorder.php`